# wp_query not resetting, last post hanging

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, post-meta

im creating a wordpress query for custom taxonomy. However im unable to get the last post that i queried to go to the permalink. Please could somebody help me get this query right, much appreciated in advance.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: taxonomy-slug
*/
?> 

<?php get_header(); ?>  

<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'business', 'town' => 'cpt-cuisine', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
<?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
     <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-inset="false">               
     <li>
     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
     <img style="margin-left: 0px; height: 65px;" alt="sample" src="<?php the_field('business_logo'); ?>" align="left"/>
     <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
     <p><?php the_field('business_slogan'); ?></p></a>
     </li>
     </ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to call [`wp_reset_query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) here, because you're not modifying the *main* query. Instead, call [`wp_reset_postdata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

You only need to call `wp_reset_query()` when modifying the *main* loop via `query_posts()` (which you shouldn't do, anyway, so you should never need to call `wp_reset_query()`).

But `new WP_Query()`, with a properly instantiated loop - i.e. one that calls `the_post()` - will stomp on the `$post` data for the main query. So, after closing your custom `WP_Query()` loop, call `wp_reset_postdata()` to restore `$post` data to the main query.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

to

```
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

As [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata) says "After looping through a separate query, this function restores the $post global to the current post in the main query"

Instead wp_reset_query destroys the previous query used on a custom Loop.

Comment: This was automatically flagged as "low-quality because of its length and content", which I am sure you don't want. Try to add more detail and explanation to avoid that.